# How can I prevent my Pixel running Android 12 from automatically updating the OS?

Tags: updates, android-12, application-autoupdate, google-pixel-6

Android is telling me it'll soon update my OS:

[image]

[image]

How can I prevent that?

I use a Pixel 6 running Android 12.

I've disabled the automated updates in the developer options:

[image]

Comment: On Pixel 4a, this works for me. In developer options disable "automatic system updates". You will still get notified (first screen shot), click the back button or go to home screen to "dismiss" that notification

Comment: @beeshyams Got it, thanks!